# Access magento installed locally from another PC in the same network

Tags: magento2, localhost

I have successfully installed and setup magento 2 on a local ubuntu server and I can access it from http://localhost

Now I want to access the site from another computer in the same network but when I call http://IP-of-host but it only shows the apache2 default page.

How do I configure?

Answer (score 0):

Update `web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` from `core_config_data` table as ip-of-hos instead of localhost.

and clear magento cache

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the local instance from another PC or system on the same network then create a virtual host first like: `http://local.magento245.com` on your system and update the base URL under the `core_config_data` table. Now check your IP address in the Ubuntu terminal by using `ifconfig` command. You will see an IP address like `192.186.1.40`. Now in the other system open the terminal and add an entry in the `host` file by using sudo nano `/etc/hosts` and add `192.186.1.40 local.magento245.com` and save the file.

Now you will be able to access the site in another system. Kindly accept the answer if it's helpful.